# jQuery AJAX call get wrong value from txt file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, readfile

I have a probme with using jQuery AJAX to read from a txt file on a server. Basically, I have 3 files, all of them are on a server in the same directory (won't be later on). One HTML file contains a button which when you click it starts an AJAX request which then sends a string (default string) to a PHP file which creates a txt files. And i have another HTML file that has a simple setInterval in 1500 ms and it get's the txt file value, and if the value is === 'default string' it makes another AJAX call that rewrites the text file to be empty. The problem is that I always get the 'default string' in the setInterval, and only if open the txt file in a browser, the ajax from the HTML2 file returns an empty string. Is this the normal behavior or am I missing something

HTML file to insert 'default string'
https://jsfiddle.net/fc6n07uz/1/

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('you clicked');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'write_to_file.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {insertValue: 'default string'},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

});
```

HTML file that reads and if string is 'default string' emptyp's the txt file
https://jsfiddle.net/ewtjy66b/1/

```
setInterval(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'textfile.txt',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if(data === 'default string') {

            console.log("I got the default string");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'write_to_file.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {insertValue: ''},
            });

        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });


}, 1500);
```

PHP file that inserts text to txt file (have in mind that the txt file is not created by PHP, I created it locally)
https://jsfiddle.net/c91jumuw/

```
<?php

$insertValue = $_POST['insertValue'];
$myfile = fopen("textfile.txt", "w+") or die("error!");
fwrite($myfile, $insertValue);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

So, why do I always get the console log from HTML2 (console.log("I got the default string");) even though i reset the value of the txt file. I know i reset it because I refreshthe txt document in a browser and it's empty, and at that time I stop getting the console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your setinterval function inside button click function,

like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button').on('click', function() {
                    console.log('you clicked');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'write_to_file.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {insertValue: 'default string'},
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        console.log("success");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    })
                    .always(function() {
                        console.log("complete");
                    });


                    setInterval(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'textfile.txt',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'text'
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
                            if(data === 'default string') {

                                console.log("I got the default string");

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'write_to_file.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: {insertValue: ''},
                                });

                            }
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            console.log("error");
                        });
                    }, 1500);


                });
            });
```

**Replace your entire jquery code with the above code,**

I have tested it and is working fine,

hope this would help you :)